# How to get XML tag value in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I have some XML in a unicode-string variable in Python as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results preview='0'>
<meta>
<fieldOrder>
<field>count</field>
</fieldOrder>
</meta>
    <result offset='0'>
        <field k='count'>
            <value><text>6</text></value>
        </field>
    </result>
</results>
```

How do I extract the `6` in `<value><text>6</text></value>` using Python?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/425313.

Comment: How to get the value preview='0' from results tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) is the most simple way to parse XML as far as I know...

And assume that you have read the introduction, then just simply use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('your_XML_string')
print soup.find('text').string
```

Comment: This finds only the first `<text>` element, regardless of position.

Comment: I had forgotten about BeautifulSoup! Didn't know that it could parse XML. Actually, I looked on their docs and you parse xml by adding an extra parameter of 'xml', i.e., `soup = BeautifulSoup('your_XML_string', 'xml')`

Answer (score 22):

With lxml:

```
import lxml.etree
# xmlstr is your xml in a string
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlstr)
textelem = root.find('result/field/value/text')
print textelem.text
```

Edit: But I imagine there could be more than one result...

```
import lxml.etree
# xmlstr is your xml in a string
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlstr)
results = root.findall('result')
textnumbers = [r.find('field/value/text').text for r in results]
```

Comment: +1 [lxml is much faster than BeautifulSoup](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2010/08/16/beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-performance/).

Comment: @bngtlrs, BS 4 will prefer lxml over most other parsers. So that point is moot, but I like the lxml API far better.

Comment: yeap, i've been switching to lxml for quite a while :D