# Get values from xml file using lxml

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

As an alternative to store user configs to database, I'm choosing now to store those configs inside a xml file. Using `lxml`, I created the following (example):

```
<root>
  <trigger name="trigger_a">
    <config_a>10</config_a>
    <config_b>4</config_b>
    <config_c>true</config_c>
  </trigger>
  <trigger name="trigger_b">
    <config_a>11</config_a>
    <config_b>5</config_b>
    <config_c>false</config_c>
  </trigger>
</root>
```

So my intention is, giving the trigger name I would like, to get the related config. Something like this, as an example:

```
print getTriggerConfig('trigger_a')

Config a is: 10
Config b is: 4
Config c is: true
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I dont want you guys to give me full solution. I found this link [How to get XML tag value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351183/how-to-get-xml-tag-value-in-python) which shows how I do it, but I created this post to see if there is something "cleaner" than the answer given. Also, I don't want to use `BeautifulSoup` since I'm already using `lxml`.

Comment: have you already tried to write `getTriggerConfig`?

Comment: @furins , not yet,  i'm still trying to discover how to get the values

Comment: I've provided a full solution, sorry :) but it is very short and based on `lxml` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the basic idea (<strike>yet untested</strike> tested):

```
from lxml import etree

f = """<root>
  <trigger name="trigger_a">
    <config_a>10</config_a>
    <config_b>4</config_b>
    <config_c>true</config_c>
  </trigger>
  <trigger name="trigger_b">
    <config_a>11</config_a>
    <config_b>5</config_b>
    <config_c>false</config_c>
  </trigger>
</root>"""

tree = etree.XML(f)
# uncomment the next line if you want to parse a file
# tree = etree.parse(file_object)

def getTriggerConfig(myname):
   # here "tree" is hardcoded, assuming it is available in the function scope. You may add it as parameter, if you like.
   elements = tree[0].xpath("//trigger[@name=$name]/*", name = myname)
   # If reading from file uncomment the following line since parse() returns an ElementTree object, not an Element object as the string parser functions.
   #elements = tree.xpath("//trigger[@name=$name]/*", name = myname)
   for child in elements:
       print("Config %s is: %s"%(child.tag[7:], child.text))
```

usage:

```
getTriggerConfig('trigger_a')
```

returns:

```
Config a is: 10
Config b is: 4
Config c is: true
```

Comment: returned: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterchildren' . I'll check out more info

Comment: Work as intended. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did a rollback to prevent the last edit from a foreign user who added a comment within the code. If you want to add notes to the answer above and aren't the original poster of the answer, it must be done as a comment.

Comment: @jeff-noel the edit was correct and solved an error in the answer (I already mentioned the possibility to parse from a file, but I forgot to say that it returns a different type of object). I accepted Thales edit and integrated it to explain why it is needed.