# PyNamecheap update the contact info

Tags: python, django, namecheap

recently I'm using [PyNamecheap](https://github.com/Privex/PyNamecheap/) to register domains as it's registering, but I want to configure my domain contacts information for each **Registrant**, **Administrative**, **Technical** and **Billing** user.

but it doesn't provide the option as looked into their [code](https://github.com/Privex/PyNamecheap/blob/fa7fc4972a0f5c446b961b90f44a44c0d7f3b7fe/namecheap/namecheap.py#L291) *they are just looping through users `contact_types = ['Registrant', 'Tech', 'Admin', 'AuxBilling']` and creating with the same details for all account types. and also there isn't any **update userinfo** method or anything*.

is there any way to update or customize them while creation and also later to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Namecheap Docs](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/intro/) says. It's just sending a `get request` as

```
https://api.sandbox.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=myuser&ApiKey=mykey&UserName=myuser&Command=namecheap.domains.setContacts&ClientIp=116.204.161.41&DomainName=mycooldomainxyz123.com&AuxBillingFirstName=Daisy&AuxBillingLastName=Smith&AuxBillingAddress1=8939%20S.cross%20Blvd&AuxBillingCity=califonia&AuxBillingOrganizationName=Org1&AuxBillingStateProvince=CA&AuxBillingPostalCode=90045&AuxBillingCountry=US&AuxBillingPhone=+1.6613102107&AuxBillingEmailAddress=john@gmail.com&TechFirstName=Daisy&TechLastName=Smith&TechAddress1=8939%20S.cross%20Blvd&TechStateProvince=CA&TechCity=california&TechPostalCode=90045&TechOrganizationName=Org1&TechCountry=US&TechPhone=+1.6613102107&TechEmailAddress=john@gmail.com&AdminFirstName=Daisy&AdminLastName=Smith&AdminAddress1=8939%20S.cross%20Blvd&AdminStateProvince=CA&AdminPostalCode=90045&AdminOrganizationName=org1&AdminCountry=US&AdminPhone=+1.6613102107&AdminCity=california&AdminEmailAddress=john@gmail.com&RegistrantFirstName=Daisy&RegistrantLastName=Smith&RegistrantAddress1=8939%20S.cross%20Blvd&RegistrantStateProvince=CA&RegistrantPostalCode=90045&RegistrantCountry=US&RegistrantPhone=+1.6613102107&RegistrantEmailAddress=john@gmail.com&RegistrantCity=california&RegistrantOrganizationName=Org1
```

it may looks **messy** **but it isn't**.
just set your **params** `ApiUser`, `ApiKey`, `UserName`, `Command`, `ClientIp`, `DomainName` and other parameters as you needed to implement your task.

in my `views.py` you have to do something like this

```
import requests

url = "above-url"
result = requests.get(url)

print(result)
```

**Note**: the result is in XML format and you could use **lxml.etree** to parse and read it. it may helps you for parsing xml. [How to get XML tag value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351183/how-to-get-xml-tag-value-in-python)